# Variable in object doesn't update unless I'm inspecting the variable during debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm currently working on three separate MVC projects at my job and only experience this issue in one of the three repeatedly.  I cannot seem to pin down exactly why it's happening.  All of the related issues I have found seem to deal with use of random number generators or something unrelated.

Anywho, here's my code that I'm currently having trouble with.

```
    public void RemoveLotFromDocument(int documentId)
    {
        Document documentWithLotToDelete = _context.Documents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == documentId);
        try
        {
            documentWithLotToDelete.LotNumber = null;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Specifically the line in the try statement.  The variable is not set to null unless I am:

- Debugging
- Stepping through the code line by line
- Inspecting the variable in Visual Studio by having the object properties expanded

For instance, if I'm debugging, insert a breakpoint in the code, step through the try statement, and expand/inspect the object at _context.SaveChanges, documentWithLotToDelete.LotNumber is unchanged.  Otherwise the code works as it's intended, sets the object to null which then allows me to delete the object (otherwise I get the expected The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint).

Another issue I read about was that perhaps there was an exception being suppressed somehow, hence the try and catch statements which doesn't catch anything funny happening.

Any ideas as to why this is happening or what I can look at that might differ in this project from my others that don't have this effect?

Comment: Could you show the Document class and the Lot class and configuration of dbcontext with relations between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> otherwise I get the expected The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

So between the lines you're giving the essential information that `LotNumber` is a reference property, not a primitive type (like `string`).

If you assign `null` to a non-null `string` property, the change tracker will notice this change and EF will save the change.

But the assignment of this reference property, `documentWithLotToDelete.LotNumber = null;`, doesn't change anything. The value is `null` at that point and just remains null. No change. If you peak at its value while debugging, lazy loading is triggered. What happens next depends on the moment when you do this:

- Before the assignment: `documentWithLotToDelete.LotNumber` is loaded, then set to `null` and a change is detected and saved.
- After the assignment: again `documentWithLotToDelete.LotNumber` is loaded, but now it doesn't change any more.

The remedy is to make sure `LotNumber` is always loaded before you (think you) modify it:

```
vardocumentWithLotToDelete = _context.Documents
                                     .Include(d => d.LotNumber)
                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == documentId);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution, made complete sense and works perfectly!